# using haml/jade in kanso couchapp

Tags: javascript, templates, couchdb, haml, kanso

following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300546/couchdb-share-functions-across-views-across-design-documents-across-database) post, I took a look at kanso.

From this I learnt that people are not afraid to load to the database context complicated modules if they need them, and that encouraged me a lot.

So I tried kanso. It gave me some trouble that implied immaturity - however, it demonstrateds a great potential.
(mostly compatibiliy view with npm, with node 0.6.x, and some open edge-cases)

So I looked a little deeper.
I saw it comes with a templates engine of it's own.

But what if I want to reuse templates that are written already by another standard?
(for example - [haml](http://haml-lang.com/), or even better - [jade](http://jade-lang.com/) that has also a nice text-to-text [JS implementation](http://howtonode.org/haml-for-javascript), and a well growing jQuery plugin - same link - see end of document ).

Does anybody here know how coupled the templates engine with the kanso types mechanism, and how simple should it be to use other template engines instead?
Or, what are the limitations I take upon myself when trying to use my own templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see in the source, [DustJS](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/) (the template engine of kanso) is not pluggable (like in expressjs for example). That being said, it probably won't be that hard to plug in a different templating engine, the code doesn't seem very complicated.

You might want to add something to [this issue](https://github.com/kanso/kanso/issues/219) on the GitHub page and request for a pluggable templating mechanism.

Comment: oups. the link to the GitHub issue is broken, can you fix it?

Comment: hmm. it could be a problem on GitHub. I'll check up later